# android http get request infinite loop

Tags: android

For some reason when I make a GET request, it seems to go into an infinite loop. I thought it was my web app having an issue, but after trying google.com, the same results occur.

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://google.com");

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.connect();

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null;) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("Client Exception " + e.getMessage());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

this code never passes the for loop. It just continues printing. Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Obviously its the conditions in the for loop. try using while loop which makes it simpler. here is a useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500107/how-should-i-read-from-a-buffered-reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line = reader.readLine() shuold  call every time when loop runs but in your code in runs once only as it is the part of initialization part ..

[image]

try somehhing like

```
for (; (line =reader.readLine()) != null;) {

    }

or 


  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {}
```

Comment: Of course, I actually meant to write for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null;) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

"line" is always the first line of the input. You need to read new lines.