# A Good Method to read files in Java

Tags: java, string, file-io, merge

I Really would appreciate it if someone can help me with this. I am trying to do external sorting and I am stuck on the part of merging. I get how I should merge it just not sure what function to use.

Right now I am trying to read in the first words of multiple small text files and store them in a string array of the size of the amount of files. So basically I will have a string array of the first word of each file. Then I determine which one is the smallest alphabetically wise and write that to a new file, after that I would read the next word of the file of that smallest word. This word would be placed in the position of the smallest word that got outputted in string array and compare it to the rest of the first word from the other file. This will keep repeating till all words are sorted.

The main problem I am running into is the fact that I was using scanner and after the first run of comparing it cant switch the smallest word with the next word in the file because scanner don't keep a point of what it has read. I know readline do but since my files are all words separated by only a white space I can't use readline. Can someone please guide me to a sufficient reading function that can't help me solve this problem.

```
  for (int i = 0; i<B;i++)
  {
  try
  {
    BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Run-"+ i + ".txt"));
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(ins);
    temp3[i] = scanner2.next();

                System.out.println(temp3[i]);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {   
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            String smallest = temp3[0];
            int smallestfile = 0;
            for(j=0;j<B;j++)
            {
                int comparisonResult = smallest.compareTo(temp3[j]);
                if(comparisonResult>0)
                {
                smallest = temp3[j];
                smallestfile = j;
                }
            }
            BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Run-"+ smallestfile + ".txt"));
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(ins);
            if(scanner2.hasNext())
            {
                temp3[smallestfile]=scanner2.next();
            }
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: Oh, please format this paragraph, break it down in multiple paragraphs. It's hard for me to read this, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda reformatted the paragraph a bit. It just I really need this done and I am really stuck at this part.

Comment: Are all the files just one line?

Comment: Basically yes it is. Cause when I sorted it, all I did is add a space between each word.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are small enough read the entire file to memory, and use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to separate the strings in arrays and do your magic.

If the the files are bigger, keep then open and read each byte until you find and space, then do it for all the files, compare the strings, do your magic and repeat until all the files reach the end.

EDIT :

- how to read the files with [BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500107/how-should-i-read-from-a-buffered-reader)
- how to split the lines with String.split()

String line = readeOneLineFromTheCurrentFile();
String[] words = line.split(" ");

Comment: If you have the time can you please write a simple example for me please. My brain is literally fried right now.

Comment: You don't have to if you don't have time. I completely understand. I don't want to look like I am asking for to much.

Comment: almost sleeping over the keyboard :) just add some small pieces in the comments, hope it guides the way !

Comment: Thanks for you attempt to help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I just wish scanner actually uses pointers so it know where it reads up too.

Comment: I am still kinda running into problem. Is there a way to keep track of which array the split is on for each file. Since Im only going to have one String array with B(the number of files) blocks of memory. It each store one word from each file. So i need some kinda of indicator for each file telling it which words of the split it has read already.

Answer (score 0):

As for temporarily sorting/storing the words, use a `PriorityQueue`  (not an array).  Sorry, I'm too busy watching baseball to add more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I kinda got the sorting part working already just by using string arrays. I really just need this part done. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understood you right, but a `Scanner` does keep the position in a file. You need just as many of them as there are files

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class so {
    // returns the index of the smallest word
    // returns -1 if there are no more words
    private static int smallest(String[] words) {
        int min = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i)
            if (words[i] != null) {
                if (min == -1 || words[i].compareTo(words[min]) < 0)
                    min = i;
            }

        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // open all files
        Scanner[] files = new Scanner[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            File f = new File(args[i]);
            files[i] = new Scanner(f);
        }

        // initialize first words
        String[] first = new String[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
            first[i] = files[i].next();

        // compare words and read following words from scanners
        int min = smallest(first);
        while (min >= 0) {
            System.out.println(first[min]);
            if (files[min].hasNext()) {
                first[min] = files[min].next();
            } else {
                first[min] = null;
                files[min].close();
                files[min] = null;
            }

            min = smallest(first);
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with

a.txt: `a d g j`
b.txt: `b e h k m`
c.txt: `c f i`

**Update**:

In your example, you open and close the file inside the outer for loop. When you reopen a file the next time, it starts at the beginning of the file, of course.

To prevent this, you must keep the file open and move the `scanner2` variable and its initialization in front of the outer for loop. You also need multiple `Scanner` variables, i.e. an array, to keep multiple files open simultaneously.

Comment: I see what you mean here but when I tried it before it didn't work. Say I have 3 files each containing 3 words. I took the first word from each file and compare it. When I find the smallest one compare to the 3 I print out that word and then from that file I would like to read in the next word that comes up. When I use scanner, it just keep giving me back the same word cause that the first word in the file.

Comment: @user2163684 This shouldn't happen, because [`Scanner.next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) says "**Throws**: NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available".

Comment: @user2163684 I didn't want to take out all of the fun, but please see the complete example.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much!! I just upload my version of the code, can you take a look and see what its not working the way it suppose to if its not to much of a burden.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to take a look at it. Is there anyway I can contact you if I need further help. if you don't mind.

Comment: @user2163684 Just leave a note here or open a chat room. It may take some time, but it won't be lost.